# how to wrap an xml tag using xmltodict python library

Tags: python, xml, xmltodict

So this is the xml output I require:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fooList action="add" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <foo>
        <bar>1</bar>
    </foo>
</fooList>
```

I am using the xmltodict python library to generate this output from a dictionary. The only problem is when I try to add the fooList tag on the top, it copies the whole string to the closing tag when it should just end in fooList. Sample of that:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <fooList action="add" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <foo>
            <bar>1</bar>
        </foo>
    </fooList action="add" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

python code:

```
entry = {
    '<fooList action="add" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance': {
        "foo": {
            "bar": 1,
        }
    }
}

xml = xmltodict.unparse(entry, pretty=True)
```

Comment: Sorry just updated the code in the question now @mzjn

Answer (score 0):

If you try the other way around you can see the mistake in your code:

```
import xmltodict

x_to_dic = xmltodict.parse("""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fooList action="add" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <foo>
        <bar>1</bar>
    </foo>
</fooList>""")
# Dictonary of xml is
print(x_to_dic)

entry = {'fooList': {'@action': 'add', '@xmlns:xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance', 'foo': {'bar': '1'}}}

dic_to_x = xmltodict.unparse(entry, pretty=True)
# XML of dictonary is
print(dic_to_x)
```

**Dictionary:**

```
{'fooList': {'@action': 'add', '@xmlns:xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance', 'foo': {'bar': '1'}}}
```

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fooList action="add" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <foo>
        <bar>1</bar>
    </foo>
</fooList>
```

Comparison;

```
Yours:
{'<fooList action="add" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance': {"foo": {"bar": 1,}}}
Generated from XML:
{'fooList': {'@action': 'add', '@xmlns:xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance', 'foo': {'bar': '1'}}}
```